# Note Timing Dropdown Menu on Garageband 10.0.3?

Tags: macbook-pro, garageband

I recently updated to Garageband 10.0.3 from 6.0.5 on my Macbook Pro. I used to be able to record a live drum set, and then adjust any issues with note timing by using a drop down menu. The options on the menu were "1/4", "1/8", "1/16", and "1/32". This would adjust the track so it would snap to the beat and be in time. This was incredibly useful, and I cannot find it anymore. Is using Flex Time editing and manually fixing each tiny mistake the only option in 10.0.3, or am I not seeing the menu?

Answer (score 1):

If the audio editor is too short it will hide some of the options.  Resize the audio editor to be taller to show the Time Quantize options which has the menu you're looking for.  Here's a screen shot:

[image: GarageBand Audio Time Quantize Screen Shot]